# List (and then delete) files that has last read-access older than 6 months

Tags: files, filesystems, timestamps, atime

**How to list files that has last read-access older than 6 months?** Then, how to delete them?

My filesystem seems to be mounted with:

```
/dev/sda3 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

Comment: On the whole machine, in your home directory only, or...?   Have you looked at the `find` command with the `-atime` option?

Comment: @StephenHarris in a specific directory containing ~ 2000 files.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to list them (NB: 180 stands for 180 days):

```
find . -atime +180
```

Here is how to move them:

```
find . -atime +180 -print0 | xargs -0 mv --target-directory=../oldfiles/
```